# Why Am I getting this error in my SELECT statement in C# WinForms to MySQL Database?

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I am getting this error:

```
Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'
```

This is my code for the Log-In button:

```
        mycon.Open();
        string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM usersettingsdb WHERE user_ID = " + textBox1.Text + "";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, mycon);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string inputpw = "";
        string dbpw = "";
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            inputpw = maskedTextBox1.Text;
            dbpw = (dr["user_pw"].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
        mycon.Close();
```

I can't quite get why I get that error since my Select statement is the same with all the other select statements I see online

Comment: start by debugging your code; check the cmdstr value and try to execute it in SQL...

Comment: Also you should look at parameters or validate the values, the query can be potentialy be used for sql injection as the value of textbox is not sanitized.

Comment: you also need to have a look at [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

enclose the textbox value in single quotes

```
 string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM usersettingsdb WHERE user_ID = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

### Edit:

As commented by Tigran. Use Parametarized queries instead just concatenating values from the controls

Comment: surely that is the reason..! So that the data entered will be treated as a separate column searches for that column in the table finds none--> raises error..! I thinks the data entered in the text box is admin right??

Comment: Important to note: **never** use directly text inside SQL string, **always** use parameters.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't quite get why I get that error

Then start debugging. Put a breakpoint on the `cmd =` line and inspect `cmdstr`'s contents. You'll see the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM usersettingsdb WHERE user_ID = admin
```

Then you'll see you need to put quotes around the username. Now go read about SQL injection, parametrized queries and DAL's.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra set of " " in your where clause surrounding the textbox1.Text otherwise you are not passing it a string.

```
string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM usersettingsdb WHERE user_ID = \"" + textBox1.Text + "\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this..

```
 string cmdstr = string.Format("SELECT * FROM usersettingsdb " + 
                "WHERE user_ID = '{0}'", textBox1.Text.Replace("'","''"));
```

Replacing `'` with `''` because sql think `'` as *escape character*.

But going with [Parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) is rocommended.

Comment: How is this preferable?  It doesn't use parameters.  I could easily get his application to select every single user in that table with a single character.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean preferable to other solutions which were posted here.. BTW, I dont know about parameters.